# function in Haskell that can solve an equation

Tags: function, haskell

I need to write a function in Haskell that can solve the following problem(physic_problem):
What is the height (in a whole number of meters) of the shortest building that you could drop a ball from such that it would take at least 5 seconds to hit the ground?
The equation can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_for_a_falling_body

I really tried hard on this and i need help!

Thank you so much!

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Can you at least show us what you tried so far?

Comment: d = g * t^2 / 2 ; t == 5 ; d >=  122.625 ?

Comment: yes enzyme how to write it in Haskell as a function, so it can gives a height in meters. I really could not define the function, if i would i will post it. Thank you guys for trying to help

Comment: This question is not in the least bit unclear, it's just not deep. Please don't misuse close reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider for instance this,

```
g :: Double
g = 9.81

dist :: Double -> Double
dist t = g * t^2 / 2
```

Then,

```
> dist 5
122.625
```

Additionally you may want to create a module out of the equations in that Wiki.

**Update**

For delivering an integral value consider for example

```
dist' :: (Integral a) => Double -> a
dist' t = ceiling $ g * t^2 / 2
```

Here we use `ceiling` (upper bound), yet note [Converting to Integral](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers#Converting_to_Integral)  for other rounding functions. Hence,

```
> dist' 5
123
```

Comment: @wadbarca Wish this helps to start up

Comment: How can I make the result only in whole number and change the output type of the dist function, so it takes Double but produce only whole number(int or Integer)?

Comment: @wadbarca note update on integral  values...

Comment: You probably want `ceil` instead of `floor`, as falling 122 meters would need less than 5 seconds :-)

Comment: @yatima2975 very true :)